# Objects Being Attached to their Creator Question

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on a rails application where one user class named (submitters) are able to login and once they are logged in they create videos. My videos controller is here:

```
class VideosController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @videos = Video.find :all

  end

  def new
    @submitter = current_submitter
    @video = @submitter.videos.build
  end

  def create
    @submitter = current_submitter
    @video = @submitter.videos.build(params[:video])
    if @video.save
      @video.convert
      flash[:notice] = 'Video has been uploaded'
      redirect_to :action => 'index'
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end

   def show
    @video = Video.find(params[:id])
  end

 def destroy
    @video = Video.find(params[:id])
    @video.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully deleted the video."
    redirect_to root_url
  end

  def update_date
    @video = Video.find(params[:id])
    @video.update_attributes(params[:video])
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully added a launch date!"
     redirect_to @video


  end
end
```

As you can probably see, I am trying to construct the controller so that when a video is created, it is created as belonging to the submitter who upload the video (via the video new view). I am using a auth system with a current_submitter method written in the application controller.

Now it lets me upload a video fine when I am logged in as a submitter. The trouble for me is working out how to display information in my view. If I want to display some columns with information about the video and then others with information about the submitter who uploaded the video, how do I go about doing that from the controller (index action), into the index view. My current view which does not work in below:

```
 <% title "Films Submitted" %>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Film Type</th>
    <th>Premiere</th>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Name</th>

   </tr>
   <% for video in @videos do %>
    <tr>
       <td><%= link_to video.title, video %></td>
       <td><%= video.film_type %></td>
    <% if video.premiere == "true" %>
       <td>Premiere</td>
    <% else %>
       <td><%= %></td>
    <% end %>  
       <td><%= video.submitter.company %></td>
       <td><%= video.submitter.name %></td>
      <td><%= link_to "Delete", video, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
<br><br>
<%= link_to "Upload a Video", new_video_path %>
```

Any suggestions or tips from rails developers would be much appreciative... I am new and trying to learn.

Video Model:

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :submitter
    has_attachment :content_type => :video, 
                 :storage => :file_system, 
                 :max_size => 50.megabytes


end
```

Submitter Model:

```
class Submitter < ActiveRecord::Base

  acts_as_authentic

has_many :videos

end
```

Schema:

```
  create_table "videos", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "description"
    t.string   "state"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "content_type"
    t.integer  "size"
    t.string   "filename"
    t.string   "film_type"
    t.boolean  "premiere",       :default => false
    t.date     "preferred_date"
    t.text     "reason"
    t.integer  "submitter_id"
    t.date     "actual_date"
  end

  create_table "submitters", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "company"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "username"
    t.string   "crypted_password"
    t.string   "password_salt"
    t.string   "persistence_token"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "video_id"
  end
```

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what happens? Do you get an error message?

Comment: Sorry, my bad... yes I get the following:

undefined method `company' for nil:NilClass

Answer (score 0):

I think you've probably only setup your associations in one direction.  You already have:

```
class Submitter < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :videos
end
```

But you also need to reciprocate that relationship in the video model:

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :submitter
end
```

This will create the `submitter` method in your video model, that references the submitter it belongs to.

**UPDATE:**

After you updated your question with the model info, I noticed one small thing: You have a video_id column on your submitters table that doesn't need to be there.  Only the "belongs_to" side of the association needs a foreign key.  But this isn't causing your problem.

I think you might have a video in your database without a submitter!  In the index action, since you're not checking for a valid submitter before you start using it, if even a single video record is missing a submitter_id, it'll break the view.

Comment: No problem.  Please post the code for the video and submitter models (you can trim down, but the class names and associations are the important part) and also the clips from your db/schema.rb that define the videos and submitters tables.  I'm sure the answer is in these.

Comment: Okay, I just updated the post. Thank you for your help! I trimmed down on the video model... the rest is the video convert logic, shouldn't be relevant.

Let me know if you need anything else!

Comment: Did you also verify that you have a submitter in the database whose id is 1?  I hate to ask because it's like asking "is your computer plugged in?" but I just want to be thorough.  Nothing in your models or schema seems to be at fault.

Comment: Glad to help!  That can be maddening.

Comment: Hey Trevor - you're new to stackoverflow, so I thought I'd point something out.  It looks like you've asked a few questions and gotten good answers, but you're not accepting answers to give those people credit.  This will make it less likely that people will be willing to answer your questions in the future.